# Properly joining in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jasper-reports, hql

I have the following problem with Hibernate:
I have got two classes:

1) Sprawozdanie

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="com.mg.shared.Sprawozdanie" table="sprawozdania">
  <id column="spr_id" name="id" type="int">
    <generator class="increment"/>
  </id>
  <property column="spr_od" generated="never" lazy="false" name="Od" type="date"/>
  <property column="spr_do" generated="never" lazy="false" name="Do" type="date"/>
  <property column="spr_typ_okresu" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="TypOkresu" type="string"/>
  <property column="spr_kurs" generated="never" lazy="false" name="Kurs" type="float"/>
  <property column="spr_dsp_nazwa" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="NazwaDysponenta" type="string"/>
  <property column="spr_dsp_adres" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="AdresDysponenta" type="string"/>
  <property column="spr_dsp_regon" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="RegonDysponenta" type="string"/>
  <property column="spr_dsp_wojew_kod" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="KodWojDysponenta" type="string"/>
  <property column="spr_dsp_wojew_nazwa" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="NazwaWojDysponenta" type="string"/>
  <property column="spr_dsp_powiat_kod" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="KodPowiatDysponenta" type="string"/>
  <property column="spr_dsp_powiat_nazwa" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="NazwaPowiatDysponenta" type="string"/>
  <property column="spr_dsp_gmina_kod" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="KodGminaDysponenta" type="string"/>
  <property column="spr_dsp_gmina_nazwa" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="NazwaGminaDysponenta" type="string"/>
  <property column="spr_dsp_typ_gminy_kod" generated="never"
   lazy="false" name="KodTypGmDysponenta" type="string"/>
  <property column="spr_dsp_typ_gminy_nazwa" generated="never"
   lazy="false" name="NazwaTypGmDysponenta" type="string"/>
  <property column="spr_dsp_zwiazek_jst_kod" generated="never"
   lazy="false" name="KodZwJTSDysponenta" type="string"/>
  <property column="spr_dsp_typ_zwt_kod" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="KodTypZwDysponenta" type="string"/>
  <property column="spr_dsp_instytucja_nadrzedna" generated="never"
   lazy="false" name="InstytucjaNadrzednaDysponenta" type="string"/>
  <property column="spr_dsp_nazwa_waluty" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="NazwaWalutyDysponenta" type="string"/>
  <property column="spr_dsp_symbol_waluty" generated="never"
   lazy="false" name="SymbolWalutyDysponenta" type="string"/>
  <property column="spr_stan" generated="never" lazy="false" name="Stan" type="string"/>
  <property column="spr_data_utworzenia" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="DataUtworyenia" type="date"/>
  <property column="spr_data_zaakceptowania" generated="never"
   lazy="false" name="DataYaakceptowania" type="date"/>
  <property column="spr_data_zatwierdzenia" generated="never"
   lazy="false" name="DataYatwierdyenia" type="date"/>
  <property column="spr_data_odrzucenia" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="DataOdryucenia" type="date"/>
   <property column="spr_data_edycji" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="DataEdycji" type="date"/>
  <many-to-one class="com.mg.spr.shared.User" column="spr_uz_login"
   lazy="false" name="Uzytkownik" update="false"/>
  <many-to-one class="com.mg.spr.shared.Officer" column="spr_dsp_id"
   lazy="false" name="Dysponent" update="false"/>
  <many-to-one class="com.mg.spr.shared.TypSprawozdania" column="spr_typ_spr_nazwa"
   lazy="false" name="TypSpr" update="false"/>
  <set name="PozycjeSprawozdania" table="pozycje_sprawozdan" cascade="all" lazy="false" >
   <key column="pspr_spr_id"  not-null="true" update="true"/>
   <one-to-many class="com.mg.shared.PozycjaSprawozdania" />
   </set>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

2) PozycjaSprawozdania

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping> 
 <class name="com.mg.shared.PozycjaSprawozdania" table="pozycje_sprawozdan">
  <id column="pspr_id" name="id" type="int">
    <generator class="increment"/>
  </id>
  <property column="pspr_nr_tabeli" generated="never" lazy="false" name="NrTabeli" type="int"/>
  <property column="pspr_nr_wiersza" generated="never" lazy="false" name="NrWiersza" type="int"/>
  <property column="pspr_dzi_kod" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="DzialKod" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_roz_kod" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="RozdzialKod" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_par_kod" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="ParagrafKod" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_par_typ" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="ParagrafTyp" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_zad_kod" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="ZadanieKod" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_zfin_kod" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="ZrodloFinansowaniaKod" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_dzi_nazwa" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="DzialNazwa" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_roz_nazwa" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="RozdzialNazwa" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_par_nazwa" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="ParagrafNazwa" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_zad_nazwa" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="ZadanieNazwa" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_zfin_nazwa" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="ZrodloFinansowaniaNazwa" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_01" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna01" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_02" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna02" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_03" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna03" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_04" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna04" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_05" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna05" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_06" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna06" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_07" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna07" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_08" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna08" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_09" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna09" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_10" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna10" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_11" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna11" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_12" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna12" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_13" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna13" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_14" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna14" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_15" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna15" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_16" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna16" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_17" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna17" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_18" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna18" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_19" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna19" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_20" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna20" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_21" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna21" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_22" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna22" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_23" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna23" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_24" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna24" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_25" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna25" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_26" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna26" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_27" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna27" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_28" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna28" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_29" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna29" type="string"/>
  <property column="pspr_kolumna_30" generated="never" lazy="false"
   name="Kolumna30" type="string"/>

  <many-to-one class="com.mg.shared.Sprawozdanie" column="pspr_spr_id"
   lazy="false" name="Sprawozdanie" update="false" insert="false"/>

 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I use a Jasperreports to generate reports. Some of data is in Sprawozdanie and some is in PozycjaSprawozdania. When I am using this query:

```
listOfData = session.createQuery("Select spr from Sprawozdanie spr left join fetch spr.PozycjeSprawozdania").list();
```

I recive this error:

```
51142 [btpool0-2] ERROR org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error a while back on my project. Turned out that in one of the entities I had forgotten to assign an annotation. In your case that would be in the XML mapping, did you miss a relationship mapping somewhere? Also, try changing the fetch type on all the relationships to eager to see if the problem goes away. if the problem does go away, change the relationships back to lazy one by one till something breaks.

Comment: I use JRBeanCollectionDataSource(), and maybe the problem exists, becasue collections must go hand in hand with Lazy?